# Text property of derived TreeNode?

Tags: c#, treeview, derived-class

I have some custom TreenodeTypes I want to fill with custom values. They look like this:

```
public class QuestionNode : TreeNode
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return string.Format("Question: {0}", Question); }
    }
}
```

When I add this Node to a treeview "trvWhatever":

```
trvWhatever.Nodes.Add(new QuestionNode { Question="WTF?"});
```

the Node is still invisible. The Treeview has the Node included, but the "Text"-Property is still null.

I understand that the base-Property is used instead of "my" property. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the base-Property is used instead of "my" property. Is there a way to change that?

Well not really. The problem is that it's not a virtual property, and you've just introduced a new property with the same name - it's not being called polymorphically.

Surely the simpler solution is just to *set* the `Text` property yourself... potentially within the constructor:

```
public class QuestionNode : TreeNode
{
    private readonly string question;

    public QuestionNode(string question)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.Text = string.Format("Question: {0}", question);
    }
}
```

You *could* do this within the property setter instead, of course:

```
public class QuestionNode : TreeNode
{
    private string question;

    public string Question
    {
        get { return question; } 
        set
        {
            this.question = value;
            this.Text = string.Format("Question: {0}", question);
        }
    }
}
```

... but personally I'd stick to the constructor version myself, unless you have some reason you need to change the question later.

Comment: I always did the "constructor"-solution but expected there would be a more elegant solution. Thanks nonetheless